# Why isnt my UI getting updated after service gets modified in another controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have one service and two controllers sharing it like below:-

```
app.factory('Initiate', function(){
  return { init: '', data: '' };
});
```

And the following two controllers:-

```
app.controller('initiate_jbolo', function($http, $scope, $compile, Initiate) {
    $scope.start = Initiate;

    $scope.change = function(){
        $scope.start['init'] = true;
        console.log($scope.start['init']);
        if($scope.start['init'] === true){
            $http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments")
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("Successful");
                // console.log(data[0].name);
                $scope.start['data'] = data[0].name;
                console.log($scope.start['data']);
            })
            .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
                console.log("Unsuccessful");
                console.log(data);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And the second controller as below

```
app.controller('jbolo_controller', function($http, $scope, $compile, Initiate) {

    $scope.start_init = Initiate;
    $scope.first_msg = $scope.start_init['data'];

});
```

and an html element to display the data shared by these two controllers in the scope of second controller:-

```
<div> {{ first_msg }} </div>
```

After getting the response from the $http service my second controller is not updating the value of `fisrt_msg`. However if I use the folowing way to display its working:-

```
{{ start_init['data'] }}
```

I am relatively new to angularjs and would appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: your factory return an object and  your controllers work with a reference to the same object. That is why this is happening

Comment: $scope.first_msg = $scope.start_init['data']; creates a reference to this then why doesnt it get updated?

Comment: It is because start_init['data'] has a reference to your object in factory and javascript is asynchronous. So while execution of second controller $scope.start_init['data'] is empty because the execution of the service hasn't finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can watch your factory variable and update it.

```
  app.factory('Initiate', function(){
      var value= { init: '', data: '' };

    return {
        getData: function () {
            return value.data;
        },
        setData: function (newData) {
            value.data= newData;
        },
        getInit: function () {
            return value.init;
        },
        setInit: function (newData) {
            value.init= newData;
        }
    };
    });
```

And change the controllers like:

```
app.controller('initiate_jbolo', function($http, $scope, $compile, Initiate) {       
    $scope.data ='';
    $scope.change = function(){
        Initiate.setInit(true);
        console.log($scope.start['init']);
        if(Initiate.getInit === true){
            $http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments")
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("Successful");
                $scope.data = data[0].name;
$scope.$watch('data ', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue !== oldValue) Initiate.setData(newValue);
});
            })
            .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
                console.log("Unsuccessful");
                console.log(data);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And second controller like this:

```
app.controller('jbolo_controller', function($http, $scope, $compile, Initiate) {
    $scope.$watch(function () { return Initiate.getData(); }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue !== oldValue) $scope.data= newValue;
    });
    $scope.first_msg = $scope.data;

});
```

Comment: It is because $scope.start_init is a reference to your variable in factory